# Sync data from salesforce to SQL database using a windows service at regular intervals

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, salesforce

I have a requirement to create a Windows service which should get the updated data from Salesforce at regular intervals based on last updated date from a table. What is the best way to achieve this?

Currently, in our web application, we are using FuseIT connector to connect to Salesforce and get the updates. However, we need a Windows service which get the updated data from a sales contact table to get the updated data at regular intervals and sync it to custom SQL database on our side.

Comment: Attempted to make it easier to read. Still needs more information from the original author.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample app that does something very similar to that: https://www.jamesward.com/2016/08/10/quick-easy-etl-from-salesforce-to-mysql-with-workflow-heroku/